# posts_nav_link() not displaying anything

Tags: posts, pagination

I'm having difficulty getting posts_nav_link() to display anything. Below is my index.php template file, I'm using permalinks (`index.php/2011/08/26/sample-post/` format) and I've currently got my `Blog pages show at most` set to `-1`.

Does anyone know why the links aren't working?

**index.php**

```
<?php
    get_header();
    $args = array('posts_per_page' => 4,'paged' => get_query_var('page'));
    $myquery = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

    <?php while ( $myquery->have_posts() ) : $myquery->the_post(); ?>

        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

        <?php the_content()?>

    <?php endwhile ?>

    <?php posts_nav_link() ?>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to do a little "hack" to get pagination to work for your custom loop.

After you define `$myquery`, do the following:

```
<?php
// globalize $wp_query
global $wp_query;
// copy $wp_query into a temporary variable
$temp_wp_query = $wp_query;
// nullify $wp_query
$wp_query = null;
// move $myquery into $wp_query
$wp_query = $myquery;
?>
```

At this point, your `posts_nav_link()` should work as expected.

Now, *after* the loop, swap the original object back into `$wp_query`, so that everything else on the page that is query-dependent will work properly:

```
<?php
// restore original $wp_query
$wp_query = $temp_wp_query;
?>
```